# String from CoreData convert to Url for VideoPlayer

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, video-player

I would like to Import a Video from the Video-Library, Save it in Documents Directory and the String from the DocumentsDirectory in CoreData as String. 
In the Second ViewController i have my VideoPlayer there i need the Url.

I need the String from CoreData and Convert it to Url in the Second ViewController. How can i do that ?

Here was the Code for Save the Video in Documents Directory and the String from the Documents Directory in CoreData as String:

```
  func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String: AnyObject]) {


        let video = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL] as! NSURL
        let rndName = NSUUID().UUIDString;

        if let videoData = NSData(contentsOfURL: video)  {
            let videoPfad = getDocDirFromSearchPath().stringByAppendingPathComponent("\(rndName).mp4")
            videoData.writeToFile(videoPfad, atomically: false)

            let newVideoEver = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("VideoData", inManagedObjectContext: self.mgdContext) as! VideoData
            newVideoEver.video = videoPfad


            do {
                try self.mgdContext.save()
                print("Save")
                print("\(newVideoEver.video)")
            } catch {
                print(error)
            }
        }

        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

}
```

In the Second ViewController i would like to get the String from CoreData and Convert it to Url:

```
 asset = AVURLAsset(URL: /* Hier i ned a Url from the CoreData String*/, options: nil)
```

Here was the Project: 
Thanks for Help

https://www.dropbox.com/sh/j16dkdcedtqeo34/AABoRLbveQUJjtSRVc8OgkOKa?dl=0

Comment: Take a look at the constructors for `NSURL`.

Comment: The Problem is How i get the String from the CoreData when i have only a ViewController. I have tried `let videoUrl = NSURL(fileURLWithPath:)` but how i can catch the String from CoreData in the ViewController? When you have time look in the Project. Thanks for Help.

Comment: I get the indexPath from Entity (VideoData) in the CollectionViewController on func didSelectItem then i have in the SecondViewController a delegate from the Entity (VideoData). I convert it to NSUrl but it comes to an Error `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
(lldb) `  on this code  `let videostring = videodata!.video!
        let videourl = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: videostring)
        asset = AVURLAsset(URL: videourl, options: nil)`. Thanks for Help